# Subscript in Windows Store Apps

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, typography, subscript

How to create a subscripted text in *Windows Store App*? 
The followed codes not work.

```
var s = new Span();
s.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "subscript" });
ITextCharacterFormat x = (ITextCharacterFormat)s;
x.Subscript = FormatEffect.On;
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Inlines.Add(s);
rtb.Blocks.Add(p);//rtb is a RichTextBlock
```

or

```
<RichTextBlock Name="rtb" Grid.Row="2" >
  <Paragraph FontSize="50" >
    Some<Span Typography.Variants="Subscript" >subscript</Span>
  </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Change `Span` to `Run`

Comment: @ChrisW. It is not work :(

Comment: your subscript is number or char? if it's number like 1,2. your code will work well.

Comment: it is strange...
It works with numbers, but I need subscripted chars for mathematical labels. I can use a smaller FontSize but I thought that is also work.

Comment: You could make a smaller fontSize as you mentioned, and then change the vertical alignment. If you wanted to make that easier, you could add both of those to custom styles for subscript and superscript, then just set the Run Style.